# Doctrine 2 не может найти родительский класс для Entity

Tags: php, composer, doctrine2

Пытаюсь начать использовать Doctrine2 в своем проекте. Решил создать абстрактный класс для избежания дублирования некоторых данных, но получаю ошибку при выполнении `vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --force --dump-sql`

Вот мои файлы:

**composer.json**

```
"autoload": {
"psr-0": {
  "MyApp\\TestApplication\\": "src/"
}
```

}

**AbstractClass.php**

```
namespace MyApp\TestApplication\Model;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
abstract class AbstractClass
{.....
}
```

**ChildClass.php**

```
namespace MyApp\TestApplication\Model;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;
use MyApp\TestApplication\Model\AbstractClass as AbstractClass;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ChildRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="test", uniqueConstraints=
 * {@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="actions_id_uindex",columns={"id"})})
 **/
class ChildClass extends AbstractClass
{...........}
```

И вот что я получаю в консоли:

```
vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --force --dump-sql
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MyApp\TestApplication\Model\AbstractClass' not 
found in 
.......\src\Model\ChildClass.php on 
line 19
PHP Stack trace:
```

Где я ошибаюсь?

Comment: А что именно находится в 19-й строке: `class ChildClass extends AbstractClass`?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev да, именно объявление класса и находится

Comment: Поменяйте `psr-0` на `psr-4` и выполните `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @DmitriySimushev сделал, но теперь Doctrine пишет `No Metadata Classes to process.`

Comment: Сбросьте кэш Doctrine.

Comment: Я нашел вот такой ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473225/doctrine2-no-metadata-classes-to-process, он мне подходит. @DmitriySimushev спасибо за совет с composer.